# Change a VBA to run automatically or when moving tabs

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the below VBA which only runs when the cell is updated. there is a formula that updates the cell but the VBA is not picking this up as a change. how do i get the VBA to run automatically so i dont have to tab inside each cell to make the VBA run. preferably fully automatic but if its easy can be a change of tab etc.

any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
     If Target.Column = 9 Or Target.Column = 13 Then 'Column I or column M
         If UCase(Target) = "YES" Then Target.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use worksheet_calculate instead?

Comment: apologies i should have mentioned that, i tried this i got: "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange

Comment: In the relevant worksheet module - use the left hand drop down at the top of the module sheet to choose "worksheet" and then select "calculate" from the right hand drop down. This will insert your event code framework for you, and you can then paste your code inside the sub end sub block.

Comment: thanks @DougCoats i tried selectionChange, it works but i would have to select every cell there is 1000s, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @DMO So let me ask you this - when you change worksheets, ou need to check columns 9 & 13 for YES and if they contain it, then 8 or 12 respectively becomes null?

Comment: @DougCoats correct but this is all populated by a formula, no one enters these values.

Comment: @HarassedDad thank you, i keep getting an error when i enter a value in the column before the code, asking me to debug, then states Object empty?

Answer (score 1):

@DMO

Here, just tested and this works perfectly. And its somewhat fast

```
Public Sub UpdatedEIghtAndTwelve()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Formula
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, z As Long

    j = UBound(arr, 1)
    z = UBound(arr, 2)

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 9) = "YES" Then
            arr(i, 8) = vbNullString
        End If
        If arr(i, 13) = "YES" Then
            arr(i, 12) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next i

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(j, z)).Value2 = arr
    End With

End Sub
```

I forgot to add that you need to put this in the worksheet Code Behind of the sheet(s) you want this run for

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
     Call UpdatedEIghtAndTwelve
 End Sub
```

Comment: You could actuall y make this alot better by passing in worksheet name and removing the active worksheet part. Thats sloppy on my end and honestly I should be shot for not doing it correctly in the firs tplace

Comment: i just placed this into the document but when i move tab etc. nothing is happening. i updated the 9 to 11 and 8 to 10, other than that i just pasted it in.

Comment: The work sheet name is "Schedule", its better than what i can do ha!

Comment: See  my edited answer. you need the second part as well! @dmo

Comment: thanks. i tested this the code sits in sheet 2 and the Private sub also sits there. i enter a value in 8 and 9 is auto populated, when i move out of the tab  it wipes all formatting, formulas etc.

Comment: Oh no. Let me get back to the drawing board. Didnt realize it wasnt putting formulas back in the cells

Comment: no worries - to throw a curve ball some cells are manually entered others are populated via a formula.

Comment: @DMO Apparently when you assign to variant array you have to use .Formula. Try again :)

Comment: Thanks. i'm not sure if this if effecting the code but the data sits in a table, when i run the above code by calling UpdatedEIghtAndTwelve the formatting gets wiped but only up to column S and the data no longer sits in a table. also it dosent seem to be removing the value? my process of testing is: update the VBA to column 11 and 10, update column 10 to YES, change tabs, come back (by this point all formatting has been removed) enter a value in column 11, leave and come back but the value in 10 is still there. any suggestions?

Comment: The issue is I have the event firing on worksheet activate. I thought per my previous question you wanted things fired on worksheet change (as in changing the worksheet). You just change the Event trigger and itll solve that. The issue with formatting is due to how we replace all the values. Is formattign important? B/c then we have a completely different issue that would need to be addressed. @DMO

Comment: as the cells are 50-50 populated manually and formula based the code didnt get picked up in worksheet_Change, so i thought maybe it would work better with a tab change. Essentially i guess it would need to be any trigger that picks up cells populated via formula. i cant seem to get the worksheet_active event working both values just sit there. as for the formatting the information is picked up from another sheet and all inside a table. the method above removes the table which causes issues when i continue the process after the above code. i hope this makes sense. @DougCoats